# CouchDB Reduce Check Box in Futon

Tags: couchdb, mapreduce, reduce, couchdb-futon

I created a small test database in CouchDB and I'm creating a temporary view in Futon. I wrote the mapper and the reducer. The mapper works, but **the check box for the reducer never shows up**. I know that there should be a check box because I've seen it when playing with views on a larger database I have.

**Why is the reducer check box not present?** Is this normal behavior? Does the reducer check box sometimes not appear? Maybe it's because my result set is small or can't be reduced for some reason? (though I see no reason why I shouldn't be able to reduce the results I have)

My mapper is this. I added the `[1, 2, 3].forEach` thing just because I thought I needed to make the result set larger in order to get the reduce check box.

```
function(doc) {
  [1, 2, 3].forEach(function() {
    emit(doc.name, 1);
  });
}
```

The reducer is this.

```
function(keys, values, rereduce) {
  return sum(values);
}
```

The results look like this:
[image]

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Refresh the page and it will show up.

It is a known bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-1778

Comment: Yeah. That worked. But why on earth is that the functionality?

Comment: It is a bug. I do not know if it is known. I will check when I will have time... but do not hesitate to report it if you can :)

Comment: Bug still present for me in v1.0.1

Comment: Bug still present in 1.3.0. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-1778

Comment: Still an issue with 1.6.1-1.